# Fitting a modified Bézier curve

Tags: curves, bezier-curve

I am connecting various vectors with a Bézier curve, using the De Casteljau algorithm. These vectors have a variety of lengths and directions, and when they are equal and orthogonal the curve (purple) is not a quadrant of a circle (blue), as *Fig. 1* shows, and I would like it to be.

If I replace the middle control point with two more, at the midpoints of the first two vectors, the (recursively drawn) curve is flatter as *Fig. 2* shows, but is now a bit too shallow.

To get an exact fit as seen in *Fig. 3*, I used a ratio of $229 / 512 = 0.447265625$ which I found by trial and error.

Can anyone please show the precise value mathematically? You might ask why I don't just draw a quadrant arc: I want to apply the same algorithm to all the other pairs of vectors.

[image]

Comment: If you search this site for “Bézier curve circular arc”, you’ll find numerous answers.

Comment: @bubba thanks for the pointer, but I've already worked out the general case from geometry myself now. The key moment was rotating the vectors so that their bisector is horizontal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want a quarter of a concave, circular arc from $(0,1)$ to $(1,0)$.  Then you can impose the following constraints on the Bézier $b:[0,1]\to\Bbb R^2$:

1. $b(0) = (0,1)$ and $b(1) = (1,0)$
2. $b'(0) ~\|~ (0,-1)$ and $b'(1) ~\|~ (1,0)$ where $\|$ means parallel and oriented in the same direction.
3. $b(1/2) = (1-1/\sqrt2, 1-1/\sqrt2)$

A cubic Bézier is determined by 8 values, namely 4 control points of dimension 2.  Constraint 1 yields the 2 control points $P_0$ and $P_3$ at the end of the Bézier.  Constraint 2 yields 2 conditions for the control points in the middle, and constraint 3 yields another 2 conditions, so that the Bézier is uniquely determined.

In particular, constraint 2 states that $P_1 = (0,u)$ and $P_2 = (v,0)$, and constraint 3 yields $u$ and $v$ (where we know that $u=v$ due to symmetry).

Doing the numerics, which I leave as an exercise, you will find
$$
u=v=\frac13(7-4\sqrt2) \approx 0.4477 \tag 1
$$

FYI, here is a [Desmos plot of a cubic Bézier](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h4wxvyg7h8) adjusted to these values.

---

**So here is the general approach:**

Suppose we want to fit a 2-dimensional curve $f$

$$\begin{align}
f: [t_0, t_1] &\;\to\; \Bbb R^2 \\
   t &\;\mapsto\; (x(t),\,y(t)) \\\tag 2
\end{align}$$

by means of a cubic Bézier $b=b_{[P_0,P_1,P_2,P_3]}$:

$$\begin{align}
b(t) &= (1-t)^3 P_0 + 3(1-t)^2t     P_1 + 3(1-t)t^2  P_2 + t^3 P_3 \\
     &= P_0 + 3(P_1-P_0)t + 3(P_2-2P_1+P_0)t^2 + (P_3-3P_2+3P_1-P_0)t^3\\
     &= P_3 + 3(P_2-P_3)(1-t) + 3(P_1-2P_2+P_3)(1-t)^2 + (P_0-3P_1+3P_2-P_3)(1-t)^3 \\ \tag 3
\end{align}$$

From the two last representations we see immediately the value of the derivatives of $b$ in the end points. We want the first derivative in the end points to point in the same direction like the derivatives of $f$ do. Thus

$$\begin{align}
P_0 &= f_0\\
P_1 &= f_0 + \alpha \cdot \dot f_{\!0}\\
P_2 &= f_1 - \beta  \cdot \dot f_{\!1}\\
P_3 &= f_1\\ \tag 4
\end{align}$$
with abbreviations like $\dot f_{\!0} = f'(t_0)$ etc.

The system aboves leaves two degrees of freedom, so we can impose that some point $Q$ is incident on the Bézier, i.e. $b(t)=(x_t,y_t)\stackrel!=Q$.
This gives a linear system that determines $\alpha$ and $\beta$:

$$
\binom{x_t-x_0}{y_t-y_0} + (2t^3-3t^2)\binom{x_1-x_0}{y_1-y_0}
~=~
3t(1-t)\binom{(1-t) \dot x_0 \quad -t \dot x_1}{(1-t) \dot y_0 \quad -t \dot y_1}\binom \alpha\beta  \tag 5
$$

For the special case $t=1/2$, and when resolved for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the system $(5)$ above becomes:

$$
\binom \alpha\beta = \frac 43\, \frac{1}{\dot x_1\dot y_0 - \dot x_0\dot y_1} \binom{\dot y_1 \quad  -\dot x_1}{\dot y_0 \quad -\dot x_0}
\binom{x_0+x_1-2x_{1/2}}{y_0+y_1-2y_{1/2}}  \\ \tag 6
$$

So all what remains is to drop in values for a concave circular arc, like e.g. $x_0=y_1=0$, $~y_0=x_1=1$,  $~x_{1/2} = y_{1/2} = 1-1/\sqrt2$, etc. to arrive at $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't understand why my 0.447265625 gives me the result I showed (but not when edited into the link you posted). With your 0.55228475 I'm not getting the quadrant shape.

Comment: You coordinates are flipped, thus you get $1-u\approx 0.4477$. Resp you are using a concave circular arc, whereas I used a convex one.

Comment: Uh of course. I'll use the $1 - u$ from your expression.

Comment: I adjusted my answer and the plot to a concave arc, so now $u=v=\frac13(7-4\sqrt2) \approx 0.4477$.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Also I extended the answer so you get a clue how the calculaton goes.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I used geometry to come up with this expression for a pair of equal length vectors which subtend an angle of $2 \theta$ where $ 2 \theta ≠ \pi$

$k$ is the ratio of the side from the common vertex where the additional 2 points will be that replace it, to make a curve from 4 control points instead of 3.

$$ k = [ \, 4 \times (\frac{1}{\cos^{2}\theta} - \frac{\tan\theta}{\cos\theta}) - 1 \, ] \, / \, 3 $$

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $2\theta$ | 90 | 75 | 60 | 45 | 30 | 15 |
| $k$ | 0.447715 | 0.495462 | 0.555556 | 0.630975 | 0.725860 | 0.846058 |

The Bézier curve is in purple, the circular arc in blue.

[image]